# How to send files from a file dialog to an external JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

So my problem is something like this:
1. I have an html page which uses a JQuery file dialog and asks the user to upload a CSV file.
2. I have a function called dialogCalled() in an external js file by the name chart_edit.js

My code functions something like this:
1. Upon successful uploading of a file on the file dialog, on the click of "OK" button, I wish to call another dialog box (let's call it dialog2) which shows the CSV data uploaded by the user converted into tabular format and shown on dialog2.
2. So in my code given below, on pressing the OK button, I wish to call the dialogCalled() function in the external js file. However, I am unable to send the files selected in the file dialog to the external js. I always get an error saying that "Uncaught reference: dialogCalled is not defined"

How should I send the files from the file dialog to the external js function or is there an alternative way?

Code:
1. The file dialog in my html file:

```
    $.FileDialog({multiple: false}).on('files.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
          files = ev.files;

          if(files.length>1){

            alert('More than 1 file not allowed');

            }
            else { 

              var text = "";
              files.forEach(function(f) {
                  text += f.name + "<br/>";
              });
              $("#output").html(text);

              //DRAWING CHART AFTER CLICK OK

              $('#chartArea').empty();
              var apiData = new FormData();
              apiData.append( 'file', files[0]);
              $("#loading").show();
              $("#myModal").css("display","block");    
              dialogCalled(files);      
            }

            //.DRAWING CHART AFTER CLICK OK


        }).on('cancel.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
            $("#output").html("Cancelled!");
        });
}
```

The id "myModal" is the div containing dialog2.

2. The function dialogCalled() which is stored in an external JS file:

   ```
   function dialogCalled(object f){
   var files = f;
   d3.text(files, function(datasetText) {


       var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

       var tbl = d3.select(".modal1-body")
                   .append("table")
                   .attr("class","data-table")
                   .attr("id","data-table");

               // headers
               tbl.append("thead").append("tr")
                   .selectAll("th")
                   .data(parsedCSV[0])
                   .enter().append("th")
                   .attr("class",function(d,i){return "col"+(i+1);})
                   .attr("id",function(d,i){return i+1})
                   .text(function(d) {
                       return d+" ";
                   })
                   .append("input").attr("type","checkbox").attr("class","form-checkbox").attr("id",function(d,i){return "col" + (i+1)});



               // data
               tbl.append("tbody")
                   .selectAll("tr").data(parsedCSV.slice(1))
                   .enter().append("tr")
                   .attr("id",function(d,i){return "row"+(i+1);})

                   .selectAll("td")
                   .data(function(d){return d;})
                   .enter().append("td")
                   .text(function(d){return d;})
                   .attr("class",function(d,i){return "col" + (i+1)})


           });
   }
   ```

Can someone please help me around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the order of the Js file

First chart_edit.js should be load, after that your js in which you write code.

Comment: Thank you...That part is working fine now! But I am facing a new problem where the files aren't being sent to the external js. I am getting this error - http://localhost/folder_name/views/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: it seems your URL is incorrect?. may be port number is missing, Please check the URL is correct.